# Android Studio create new project in Mac gives a Parse Initialization error when running in windows

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform, android-gradle-plugin, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am new to Android development, I am using Android studio.

When I Create a new project in Mac, it runs fine but as I clone it to my windows device, it shows an error of Parse Initialization. Also I am using Parse, facebook sdk has been installed and jar files are included in ../libs/

Comment: Please share the error in the question itself

Comment: the error is Parse Initialization Error.